# Building Gstreamer 1.0.5 on Windows

Tags: c++, gstreamer, glib

I have the projects setup as described in the readme, and have GLib 2.28.8 installed and compiling. When I get to compiling gstreamer, I get thousands of errors that indicate to me that something is wrong with the build setup or with GLib versions. I couldn't find an easy source of other GLib versions for windows (I've tried both the dev and sources version of GLib here: http://www.gtk.org/download/win32.php ).

The first compile error is:

```
...\build\gstreamer-1.0.5\gst/gstobject.h(170): error C2079: 'lock' uses undefined struct '_GMutex'
```

In gstobject, lock is defined as:

```
GMutex         lock;        /* object LOCK */
```

Which Visual studio finds as defined in gthread.h

```
typedef struct _GMutex          GMutex;
```

So everything looks fine to me, but maybe I'm overlooking something. glibconfig.h also defines _GMutex* as GStaticMutex, could that be interfering?

Comment: Is `struct _GMutex` also defined?

Comment: In glibconfig.h, there's this: 
typedef struct _GMutex* GStaticMutex;

Comment: That typdef defines GStaticMutex, please check where `struct _GMutex` itself is defined.

Comment: Of course - I couldn't find where _GMutex is defined in GLib.

Comment: After doing some more digging, I found that _GMutex, _GCond, and _GPrivate all have typedef struct's for their underscore-less counterparts (GMutex, GCond, and GPrivate), but don't seem to have any definition themselves. (Looking in GLib itself here). Though compiling GLib seems to work just fine, but GStreamer doesn't seem to like that. Thoughts? Plain C isn't really my language, so maybe I'mm missing something.

Comment: There was a recent discussion about that issue when building on windows using mvc and _not_ cygwin, you should take a look at that. The solution - as far as I remember - was to include gutils.h, but there alse appeared a bunch of fixes (regarding glib/gtk+)

Comment: I ran into this issue again on another project. The issue was a separate, older glib install that Windows was picking up during installation. Removing the older glib resolved the issue. For folks looking to compile GStreamer, they now put out binaries for most platforms.

Answer (score 2):

I am using glib.2.28.8, also encountered the same problem. The following two threads ([1](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=72085) and [2](http://gtk.10911.n7.nabble.com/Building-gtkmm-on-windows-td79888.html)) also discuss the related problem.

In my case, just add

```
struct _GMutex
{
  /*< private >*/
  gpointer p;
  guint i[2];
};
```

before

```
struct _GMutex GMutex;
```

Comment: Ah - good to know there's a solution. Thanks for following up. For anyone that got here from the original issue, gstreamer has started putting out builds for all platforms: http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/download/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to update your Glib to 2.32.0

I successfully build GStreamer-1.0.5 both on Linux and Windows Xp, with Glib 2.32.4

See configure.ac

dnl GLib

GLIB_REQ=2.32.0

AG_GST_GLIB_CHECK([$GLIB_REQ])